# How to toggle between two values of concurrent table rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a table name `[NavBar]` with these columns:

```
Id [int]
Name [nvarchar]
DisplayOrder [int]
```

Sample data:

```
Id   Name   DisplayOrder
---------------------------
 100   Home        1
 101   Products    2
 102   Contact     3
 103   Career      4
```

How do I perform update operation to toggle between two rows `DisplayOrder` of `two concurrent rows` (order by `Displayorder`) ?

For example `Contact = 4, Career = 3`

Expected output:

```
100  Home      1
101  Products  2
102  Contact   4
103  Career    3
```

Input parameter: `Id` of one row only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating id = 102 (and then 103)

```
 drop table navBar;
 create table navBar
 (Id [int],
Name [nvarchar] (200),
DisplayOrder [int]);

insert into navBar
values
 (100,   'Home'      ,  1),
 (101,   'Products',    2),
 (102 ,  'Contact',     3),
 (103  , 'Career',      4);

 declare @id int;

 set @id = 102

 ; with t as(
 select id,  name, DisplayOrder, 
        lag(id) over(order by DisplayOrder) lgid, 
        lag(DisplayOrder) over(order by DisplayOrder) lgDisplayOrder,
        lead(DisplayOrder) over(order by DisplayOrder) ldDisplayOrder
 from navBar)
 update t
   set DisplayOrder = case @id when id then ldDisplayOrder else lgDisplayOrder end
 where (@id = id and ldDisplayOrder is not null)
   or  (@id = lgid);


 select * from navBar;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Id  Name    DisplayOrder
100 Home    1
101 Products    2
102 Contact 4
103 Career  3
```

Comment: @BimalDas Why? It's working fine. You should start your `with` with semicolon

Comment: @BimalDas if you are trying to update the last row, What should happen?

Comment: I shall restrict from code maybe ? ya there is an issue.

Comment: @BimalDas ok,done. If parameter id is the last displayOrder, it won't update anything

Comment: will it work if Id is different data type like uniqueidentifier on nvarchar ?

Comment: @BimalDas yes, just change `@declare @id nvarchar`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work

```
declare @Id int = 101

update t1 
set Id = new_ID + @Id
from NavBar t1
inner join  (select DisplayOrder, row_number()  over (order by DisplayOrder) as new_ID
            from NavBar where Id > @Id) as t2  on t2.DisplayOrder = t1.DisplayOrder
```